# Qual é classe para desenhar circulo no Android?

Tags: java, android, classes

Conheço a Classe `Rect` para retângulo e para circulo

```
 private Rect retangulo = new Rect();
```

Qual é classe para desenhar circulo no Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe o [`OvalShape`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/OvalShape.html), veja na [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/OvalShape.html). Exemplo:

```
OvalShape circle = new OvalShape(); 
circle.resize(50f * mDensity, 50f * mDensity);
```

Imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja alguns exemplos de aplicação em [Codota para Android](https://www.codota.com/android/classes/android.graphics.drawable.shapes.OvalShape).

Answer (score 2):

Existe o `OvalShape` que consegue ser usado como um círculo também.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/OvalShape.html

Usaria assim:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  super.onDraw(canvas);
  OvalShape shape = new OvalShape();
  shape.setWidth(10);
  shape.setHeight(10);
  shape.draw(canvas, paint);
}
```

sendo que um oval que tem o mesmo largura e o mesmo altura seria um círculo.